# Why does the code not show up with error?

Tags: python

```
animals = ["aardvark", "badger", "duck", "emu", "fennec fox"]

animals.insert(duck_index, "cobra")

duck_index = animals.index("duck")

print animals
```

Since I didn't define what `duck_index` is at line `3` yet, why does the code still work?

Comment: please  show your text code, don't link to a image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duck_index` must already be assigned - this can happen in various different places.  If it's a web interface, you have no idea what they have already defined; if its ipython it may have been defined in the history.

Answer (score 0):

python is a dynamically typed language. You don't have to declare or specify type before declaring.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the question is not about that.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure that a certain value (let's call it "duck") is in your list and you want to insert a new item in your list before that "duck" value without knowing its index, handle it like this:

```
animals.insert(animals.index("duck"), "cobra")
```

Let me know if it suit your need.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I would like to figure out this question in other words please